# AngularJS: Is a factory a singleton?

Tags: angularjs

Is a factory a singleton? If it is, what is the difference between a factory and a service? When should each be used?

Answer (score 2):

Yes mate, factories and a services are both Singletons.

Generally it's preference which to use, but generally the community more leans toward factories because they are easier to invoke.

this question is a duplicate of this:

[service-vs-provider-vs-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory)

Also this is a really good styling with a lot of helpful information:

[John Papa styling guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#services)

I hope that helps